# Adding icon next to user_id column in listview from imagelist

Tags: vb.net, listview, imagelist

I have no idea how to add icon in `listview`. I have `imagelist` that has one .ico item in its collection. My code till now looks like this.

```
Private Sub filllvwStudentColumnHeaders()
    ' add a column width 140 and left alignment
    lvwStudent.Columns.Add("User ID", 140, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lvwStudent.Columns.Add("Lastname", 140, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lvwStudent.Columns.Add("Firstname", 140, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lvwStudent.Columns.Add("Middle Initial", 140, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lvwStudent.Columns.Add("User Level", 140, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lvwStudent.Columns.Add("User Name", 140, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lvwStudent.Columns.Add("Password", 140, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
End Sub

Private Sub FilllvwStudent()

    Dim sql = "select 1 user_id,'micevski' lastname, 'sasko' firstname, 'sm' midle, '1' level, 'sasko1' username,'123' password from test union select 2 user_id,'micevski1' lastname, 'sasko1' firstname, 'sm1' midle, '11' level, 'sasko11' username,'1231' password from test"
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim r As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim Conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
    Conn.Open()
    Dim Cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, Conn)
    r = Cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    If r.HasRows Then
        While r.Read()
            With lvwStudent.Items.Add(r("User_id"))
                .SubItems.add(r.GetValue(1))
                .subitems.add(r.GetValue(2))
                .subitems.add(r.GetValue(3))
                .subitems.add(r.GetValue(4))
                .subitems.add(r.GetValue(5))
                .subitems.add(r.GetValue(6))
            End With

        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

What i tried is

```
lvwStudent.LargeImageList = ImageList1 
lvwStudent.Items.Add("ok1", 0)
```

`0` means that the index of the image in the `imagelist` is `0`.
This code adds 'ok1' to the list but there is no icon...

I am starting to think that this is not possible to be done in vs 2003 , hope someone can help me doing this.

Comment: According to your code you added "ok1" to the listview?

Comment: the code that i tried was just to try if it will add ok1 to the listview. And it was added , but without icon

Comment: Try using `SmallImageList` instead of `LargeImageList`. I assume you are in Details view mode, which needs `SmallImageList`

Comment: No change... i have this properties for imagelist ColorDepth 8bit,imagesize 32x32